# WAR does not work under JBoss, but exploded application - works

Tags: java, jboss, jboss5.x

From time to time we have very strange problem - if we deploy war into JBoss then our application(JSF+Spring+Hibernate) does not work.
But if use exploded deployment then everything works ok.
We have such problems very rarely.
At the same time on one box the same war does not work, but on another - works normally.
Boxes are the same - the same JBoss 5.1 and the same Java 1.5, etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately JBoss still has hot-deployment issues, that behaviour is rather random, as you have noticed.

You can try this approach, it should be more reliable

$JBOOS_HOME/bin/twiddle invoke "jboss.system:service=MainDeployer" deploy /my/path/to/app/myapp.war

Comment: But war was not hot deployed.
We restarted JBoss after deployment.

Comment: Hmmm, then I am stuck. Are there any information in logs? Try to switch to TRACE level of logging, maybe something would show up.

Answer (score -1):

After deploying your application's war to Jboss. Restart Jboss server.
Open url :

```
http://localhost:8080/web-console/
```

(modify as per  port and hostname of your server)

It will show your status of Jboss server. Open J2EE domains nodes(from left hand tree). click on jboss.local.management-->Jboss, you will see the list of WAR deployed inside jboss server.

Comment: And what? How does it help me?

Comment: This is just one way to verify that whether the application WAR is deployed properly after jboss restart. It will help you in verifying that the application is deployed or not.And if its deployed and you are not able to access the same.

Comment: Unfortunately we use web configuration.
And web-console does not work in web configuration.